# Change scrapy logging level does not work

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I crate my first spider, but I would like to see only my output and no INFO or DEBUG messages. According to scrapy [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.5/topics/logging.html#topics-logging-settings) I should use `--loglevel/-L LEVEL` but when I start my scrapy like this:

```
scrapy crawl -L WARNING myspider
or
scrapy crawl --loglevel=WARNING myspider
```

I can see all INFO messages. How can I change that, what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

UPDATE1:
Versions:
Scrapy 1.5.1
Python 3.6.5

My spider class:

```
class specialspider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
        "https://webpage.cz/",
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Comment: this looks like a bug, could you share your python and scrapy versions? And I would say also your entire project on how to replicate it.

Comment: I updated my versions and code under UPDATE1.